# Ivy: Configurations. Am I missing something?

Tags: ivy

When I first started using Ivy, I asked about configurations, and was pointed to [Lightguard's blog post on the subject](http://lightguard-jp.blogspot.com/2009/04/ivy-configurations-when-pulling-from.html). I found it extremely helpful. However, I now have a question about the *provided* configuration that this post (and others) have. The configuration item looks like this:

```
<conf name="provided" 
    visibility="public" 
    description="this is much like compile, but indicates 
         you expect the JDK or a container to provide it. 
         It is only available on the compilation classpath, 
         and is not transitive."/>
```

I divided up the `description` parameter, so it's easier to see. Notice it says "*and is not transitive*".

How does Ivy know that the `provided` configuration is not transitive? The configuration doesn't have the `transitive="false"` parameter. Is it because of the way this configuration would interact with a Maven repository that makes it non-transitive? Or, is this a minor *glitch* that everyone has copied from one blog to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the ivy configuration description is intended to mirror the corresponding scope description in the [Maven docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope):

> **provided**
>
> This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and *is not transitive*.

As for how ivy translates this scope into an ivy configuration mapping, I'd have to download a Maven module containing a "provided" scope dependency to check.

## Update

Needs to be remembered that ivy performs a translation of how scopes are working in Maven. An example module would be:

- [jetty-servlets](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.eclipse.jetty%7Cjetty-servlets%7C9.0.0.M1%7Cjar)

Its POM contains two "provided" scope dependencies which are translated by ivy into the following ivy dependencies:

```
<dependency org="org.eclipse.jetty" name="jetty-webapp" ... conf="provided->compile(*),provided(*),runtime(*),master(*)"/>
<dependency org="org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" name="javax.servlet" ... conf="provided->compile(*),provided(*),runtime(*),master(*)"/>
```

The key point is that neither of these dependencies are mapped to the following ivy configurations:

- default
- compile

This means they won't get pulled down as transitive dependencies when you declare a dependency against [jetty-servlets](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.eclipse.jetty%7Cjetty-servlets%7C9.0.0.M1%7Cjar).

## Update

When downloading a Maven module, ivy performs a translation between the rigid scope system into ivy configurations that mimic the same operation. So when you you declare the following configuration mapping "provided->default" in **your** module, you're pulling down the remote modules "compile" dependencies into your local "provide" configuration (The "compile" scope is the default in Maven and also in an ivy translated Maven module).

To retrieve the remote "provided" dependencies you'd have to specify "provided->provided", which is possible using ivy, but not an operation supported by a Maven module.

Comment: So, it's not the configuration, but my mapping that makes it transitive? If I have a provided jar, I should not be mapping to `provided->default`? I was always under the impression that configurations in Ivy are anything you want, and it is a _custom_ to map them to Maven scopes.

Comment: Okay, in my `ivy.xml` `<dependency>`, Saying `provided->compile` and `provided->default` is the same (if I'm talking to a Maven repository). Both map to the Maven "compile" and are transitive. Right? If I map to `provided->provided`, that will be a non-transitive pull. Or, I can add the `transitive=false` to my `<configuration>` entity when I define that particular configuration. Right?

Comment: @DavidW. You're asking two questions and you're correct with both. What I'd like to add is that I don't like the "transitive=false" dependency option. A slicker alternative is map to the Maven module's "master" ivy configuration "compile->master", this will retrieve only the remote module's artifact without any transitive dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. It sometimes takes me a few times before I catch on, but once I do, I learn very well. For example, if I stick a knife in an electric outlet a few times, I'll realize that's not a good idea, and I should try a fork. So, the mapping to `default` or to `compile` in a Maven repo will be transitive because these Maven configs are transitive in themselves. If I don't want a transitive property, I'll map to `master`. No need to declare a configuration as `transitive=false` if you're mapping to a Maven repo.